# $http POST server error

Tags: angularjs, django, http, django-cors-headers

I am having an issue when trying to POST data. My server keeps rejecting my data (500 server error).

Is it the way I have it formatted? I noticed in my console in Response Headers it says "Content-Type:text/html". Should that say JSON?

In python, this works fine:

```
requests.post('http://test.net/item/291/', {'uid':21, 'click':1, 'like':1, 'image':0, 'scroll':1, 'clickbuy':0})
```

I setup a middleware file which includes:

```
class CorsMiddleware(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        response['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'
        return response
```

My AngularJS app is setup like this:

```
.factory('cardsApi', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var like = JSON.stringify({uid:21, click:1, like:1, image:0, scroll:1, clickbuy:0}));

        var postLikes = function (product_id) {
            return $http.post('http://test.com/api/item/' + product_id, like);
        }

        return {
            postLikes: postRecordLikes
        };
    }])

.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
})
```

The error (in browser):

[image]

Comment: Your server is having trouble handling the request. Try removing the `stringify` bit, so `var like = { blah blah blah };`

Comment: Did you mean remove the entire  JSON.stringify? I did this, still getting the 500 error. I noticed in Response headers it says Content type is Text/html

Comment: Well without any more info it looks like a problem with the server code, not angular. Try setup a fiddle that showcases the problem.

Comment: Sure, I've done that here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ScnGyy2eAmGwcJ7XZ2Z?p=preview

Comment: @Ycon the 500 error means there was a Python exception raised while processing the request. Look at your terminal output that is running your Django development server. There should be a traceback when the error occurs. Can you post a pastebin of that traceback?

Comment: Wow- there's a "Preview" windows in Network (google chrome extension). It's because of the trailing slash. http://dpaste.com/2HFQH99. Would this work? $http.post('http://test.net/api/item/' + product_id, '/', like);

Comment: can you display the response you have under the response tab of your browser? it would contain django traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the exception value at the bottom of the [traceback you pasted](http://dpaste.com/2HFQH99).

```
Exception Value: You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to stashdapp-t51va1o0.cloudapp.net/api/item/37/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.
```

For POST requests, make sure the URL matches the pattern defined in your `urls.py` (or in whatever 3rd party Django app you're using that may be defining the URL patterns for you). In this case, your URL pattern includes a trailing slash, so you must include one with the URL for your POST request.

By default, Django automatically redirects URLs *without* trailing slashes to URLs *with* trailing slashes, but for POST requests you'll lose the submitted data and this exception will be raised.

p.s. Unless you've tried it already and there's some reason it doesn't work well for you, I'd definitely recommend using the [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) app as opposed to rolling your own middleware to deal with CORS.